# How to merge 2 views in MVC design pattern?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, model, controller

I am trying to implement the Model-View-Controller architecture design pattern on my small project.
What I'm trying to achieve is to extend the basic view with a template.

> Template `base_view.phtml`

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title><?= $html_title ?></title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Main content -->
    
    <main class="container">
       <!-- I am trying to load a template by calling this controller method -->
       <?= $this->showSection('content'); ?>
    </main>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ==================================================== -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

> In the `<main>` element I am trying to load the template by calling the controller method
> `$this->showSection('content');` - Here is the `home_view.phtml` template

```
<!-- template base_view.phtml -->
<table class="table table-stripped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Lastname</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">e-mail</th>
        <th scope="col">Edit</th>
        <th scope="col">Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php if (isset($rows)) : ?>
        <?php foreach ($rows as $row) : ?>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><?= $row['id'] ?></th>
                <td><?= $row['date'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['lastname'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['name'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['email'] ?></td>
                <td><a href="<?= "edit/" . $row['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="<?= "edit/delete/" . $row['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endif ?>
</tbody>
```

> My `HomeController.php`,

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Core\BaseController;

use App\Models\MemberModel;

class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    protected array $sections = ['content' => 'home/home_view.phtml'];

    public function index(): void
    {
        // .... working with the model and loading data from the database ....
        // I load the template, insert variables for home_view.phtml
        $this->view(ctx: ['html_title' => 'Administration Panel', 'rows' => $db_data]);
    }
}
```

> The `view()` method logic is inside the BaseController abstract class

```
<?php
/* BaseController.php */

namespace App\Core;

abstract class BaseController
{
    protected string $base_view = 'base_view';

    protected array $section = array();

    protected array $renderSection = array()

    function __construct(){}
   
        
    // I load base_view.phtml and simultaneously load home_view.phtml 
     // which is defined in class properties in HomeController.php.
     // I load the content of the template into the class property `protected array $renderSection` 
   
    protected function view(string $section = '', array $ctx=[])
    {
        $this->context = $ctx;
        $base_view = str_replace('\\', '/', self::DOCUMENT_ROOT) . "../Views/{$this->base_view}.phtml";
        $_sections = $sections ?? $this->sections;

        foreach ($_sections as $section => $file) {

            $template = str_replace('\\', '/', self::DOCUMENT_ROOT) . "../Views/{$file}.phtml";
            if (file_exists($template)) {
                // loading the home_view.phtml template
                ob_start();
                require($template);
                $this->renderSection[$section] = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
            }

        }
        if (file_exists($base_view)) {
            // Load base_view.phtml directly into the client browser.
            extract($this->context);
            ob_start();
            require($base_view);
            $body = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
        
            echo($body);
    }
    
    protected function showSection(string $section)
    {   
        return $this->renderSection[$section];
    }
}
```

This solution only works when loading static content of template home_view.phtml. Not when rendering the template and dynamically loading the variables in the template.
Can someone advise me how to merge two views? How to correctly and efficiently render the home_view.phtml template in to base_view.phtml?
Thank you.

Comment: Those are templates, not views.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be solved.
I tried moving the `extract()` function above the `foreach` loop in the view method inside `BaseController.php` and everything now renders correctly.